# Running Ubuntu 9.10 as a virtual machine on a Windows 7 Host

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

Running Ubuntu 9.10 as a virtual machine on a Windows 7 Host

Anybody got the steps for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice tutorial: [**Installing Ubuntu 9.10 as a Virtual Machine in Windows**](http://www.petri.co.il/installing-ubuntu-9-10-as-a-virtual-machine-in-windows.htm)

It requires VMware and an Ubuntu installation CD/iso

But I would also like to point out that you could run:

- [Portable Ubuntu](http://portableubuntu.demonccc.com.ar/)
- [Ubuntu on a USB stick](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/create-a-ubuntu-9-10-live-usb-in-windows/)
- [Ubuntu installed within Windows (using Wubi)](http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/2361254/install_ubuntu_910_alongside_windows.html)

Comment: I know, but I couldn't find a tutorial for it that fast ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this using sun Virtual Box... for free.

- http://www.virtualbox.org/